# Intersection on text object as two colours in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I have the following logo design and basically I want to get red text on white background and vice versa.

I tried to convert the text with `Path -> Object to Path` and then do `Path -> Intersection` or `Path -> Difference`, but nothing seems to work.

I seem to be missing a crucial step or some deeper understanding of how shapes and text relate to one another.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Inkscape, most boolean operations only work on two paths. So here's a method to achieve that:

1. Select the text, and do *Path > Object to Path*, to convert the text to outlines.
2. Ungroup the text, and do *Path > Combine*. This will create a single combined path.
3. Ungroup the squares, select them all, and do *Path > Combine*. Again this will create a single combined path.
4. Select both combined paths (i.e the text and squares), and do *Path > Intersect*

Remember that Intersect will consume the square shapes, so if you want those back, copy them before you apply the operation. Then you can do *Edit > Paste in place* to get them back, then do *Object > Lower to bottom*, to get the squares back under the text. You can obviously then select the text, and change the fill colour.

Answer (score 0):

Make two text versions - red and white. Let the white be on top and use a copy of the red shape as a clipping path for it.

You already tried Boolean operations. They need the text as converted to path as you seemingly know. But both pieces to be intersected must also be single entities. You must Ungroup and then combine multiple pieces with Path > Combine.

I recommend to use the clip method. It's non-destructive and no conversion to path or combining is needed, the shapes can be made to single entities by grouping.

So group your rectangular pieces, bring them on top of the text, select all and apply Object > Clip > Set

Comment: Hey yeh I tried literally that exact thing haha maybe I'm not converting to path properly... is there a certain way I need to select the text? Like with the pointer V using the text button?

Comment: Did you also ungroup and  combine the pieces? Intersection and other boolean operations need single entities.

Comment: Once I succeeded in doing that. There was some non-obvious trick I cannot remember unfortunately. Did you play with reverting the path direction?

Comment: No such movement is needed.